# What is a routed block?

Tags: ip

I'm reading a scientific paper about NTP DDoS attacks ([here](http://mdbailey.ece.illinois.edu/publications/imc14-ddos.pdf)) and they wrote "routed block" multiple times. I can't figure out what they're talking about.

Could someone explain me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of this paper, you can substitute the words "advertised prefix."

Answer (score 1):

This presumably refers to the CIDR "hierarchical blocks of IP addresses" from [RFC 4632](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4632).

> ...prefixes may be defined to describe any power of two-sized block of
> between one and 2^32 end system addresses.